# How to make EC2 instance call another instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, communication, instance

I have two EC2 instances.  I want that if one finish a job, it will sign the other one to do other stuff.
So, how to make the communication?  I don't want to use CURL.. coz it seems like expensive.  I think AWS should have some simple solution but I still can't find relevant help in the documentation.

:(

also, how to send data between two instances without giong through SSH in a fast way?  I know ssh can be done. but it seems slow.  once again, any tool that EC2 provide to do that?

---

Actually, I need two  methods:

1) Instance A tells Instance B to grab the data from Instance A.

- This is answered by Adrian that I can use SQS.  I will try that.

2) Once Instance B get the signal, then the data (EBS) data in Instance A needs to transfer to Instance B.  The amount of data can be big even I zip it.   It is around 50 MB.  And I need Instance B to get the data fast so that Instance B will have enough time to process the data before next interval comes in.

So, I am thinking of either these methods:

a) Instance A has the data dump from DB, upload to S3. Then signal Instance B.  Instance B gets the data from S3.

b) Instance A has the data dump from DB.  Then signal Instance B.  Instance B establish SSH (or any connection) to Instance A and grabs the data.

The data may need to be stored permanently but it is not a concern at this moment. It is mainly for Instance B to process.

This is a simple scenario.  I'm thinking of what if I scale it with multiple instances, what the proper approach is.  :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How fast do you need this communication to be?  SSH is pretty darn fast.  The only thing that I can think of that might be faster is raw sockets (from within whatever program is running the jobs).

Comment: actually, is S3 faster or SSH faster?   I think SSH is faster, right? because it is direct connection, right?

Comment: S3 is a storage mechanism, not a communication channel.  If you were to use S3 for signalling, you'd have to constantly poll from the second machine to see if the first machine had stored some signal value.  It would be at least an order of magnitude slower than SSH in the best case.  The Amazon services (S3, SQS, etc) are designed for fault tolerance, not speed.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has a special service for this -- it's called [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs), and it allows instances to send messages to each other through special queues. There are SDKs for SQS in various languages, like [Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava) and [PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp). This should serve your signaling needs.

For actually sending the bulky data over, it's best to use S3 (and send the object key in the SQS message). You're right that you're introducing latency by adding the extra middle-man, but you'll find that S3 is *very* fast from EC2 instances (if you put them in the same availability zone, that is), and more importantly than performance, S3 is very reliable. If you try to manage the transfer yourself through SSH, you'll have to work out a lot of error checking and retry logic that S3 handles for you. You can use [S3FS](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs) to easily write and read to/from S3 from EC2.

*Edited to address your updated question.*

Comment: If the OP feels that raw SSH or curl is too slow, then SQS is going to seem glacial, no?

Comment: Hmm let me look it up.  Thanks.  do you know how much data can be sent through SQS?

Comment: I don't think he's realistically going to do any better. There's no guarantee that two instances even in the same availability zone will necessarily be in the same physical network, so I don't see how you can do significantly better than going over the internet. EC2 and SQS, on the other hand, probably *do* have some sort of direct connection. SQS from within EC2 is really quite fast...

Comment: @seatoskyhk I'm not sure how much data an SQS message can contain, but it's probably not too much. It's meant more for signalling and message-passing rather than large-scale data transfer. I got the sense from your question that this is what you were looking for ('signalling'). If you want to actually send large amounts of data between instances, that's probably a different story...

Comment: I checked the API reference, and the largest message size a queue can be configured for is 64KB. Not sure if that's enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks.  See my additional info above... :)

Comment: @Adrian  oh. .you are the author of aws sdk  :)

Comment: @seatoskyhk Not exactly, I was just an intern on the Java SDK team at Amazon when it was being written. Most of it was done by my mentor, Jason. I do maintain the SDK port for running AWS on Google App Engine though :)

Comment: @Adrian  so if I have a lot of data want to transfer from one instance to another in a fast way, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/)... which is kind of like push SQS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a distributed workflow managing service.

If Instance B has already completed the task, it can go on to pick another task. Usually, you would want Instance B to signal that is has "picked" up a task and is doing it. Then other instances should try to pick up other tasks on your list. You need a central service which knows which task has been picked up already, and which ones are left for grabs.

When Instance B completes the task successfully, it should signal the central service that it is free for a new task, and pick one up if there is something left.

If it fails to complete the task, the central service should be able to detect it (via heartbeats and timeouts you defined) and put the task back on the list so that some other instance can pick it up.

[Amazon SWF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-welcome.html) is the central service which will provide you with all of this.

For data required by each instance, you should put it in a central store like s3, and configure s3 paths in a way such that each task knows where to download data from, without having to sync up.
e.g. data for task 1 could be placed in something like s3://my-bucket/task1